# C# update two text boxes at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Let's say I have two text boxes, one holds binary data and the other it's ASCII equivalent. If the user let's say changes either one of them, how would i have the other text box updated at the same time, without having to press a button?

Comment: use textchanged event for detail check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Look at the textchange event you will need to be careful so as to make sure you dont find yourself in a loop of changing one cos the other said it changed but it changed cos you changed it

Comment: `textchanged` in both text box will creates an infinite loop

Comment: Yep I mentioned that the best way out of us it is to unset the onchange depending on which has focus

Comment: Of course - carelessly using TextChanged will create a loop. However since TextChanged is directly called when the change is made, you can set a flag (aka `manualChange`) in order to ignore a change.

Comment: @un-lucky There is no infinite loop when you use `TextChanged` event of two `TextBox` controls to sync text of them. The `Text` property checks and if the new value is the same as previous value, then it will not raise the `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to prevent an *infinite loop* (`asciiTextBox` changes `binaryTextBox.Text` which changes `asciiTextBox.Text` etc.), and you can implement something like that:

```
private void asciiTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  binaryTextBox.TextChanged -= binaryTextBox_TextChanged;

  try {
    binaryTextBox.Text = BinaryText(asciiTextBox.Text);
  }
  finally {
    binaryTextBox.TextChanged += binaryTextBox_TextChanged; 
  }
}

private void binaryTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  asciiTextBox.TextChanged -= asciiTextBox_TextChanged;

  try {
    asciiTextBox.Text = AsciiText(binaryTextBox.Text);
  }
  finally {
    asciiTextBox.TextChanged += asciiTextBox_TextChanged;
  }
}
```

Comment: well detailed answer :)

Comment: Hmm i think i get it. The only thing i don't exactly get is binaryTextBox.TextChanged -= binaryTextBox_TextChanged; what is happening at this line? Sorry, i'm new to OOP :p

Comment: There is no infinite loop when you use `TextChanged` event of two `TextBox` controls to sync text of them. The `Text` property checks and if the new value is the same as previous value, then it will not raise the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: @Rafas: I temporary *switch off* `binaryTextBox`'s`TextChanged` event while changing `binaryTextBox.Text` and then switch it back *on* (to let user change `binaryTextBox`)

Answer (score 2):

Surely you don't need to unregister `TextChanged` event and register it again!

There is no infinite loop when you use `TextChanged` event of two `TextBox` controls to sync text of them. The `Text` property checks and if the new value is the same as previous value, then it will not raise the `TextChanged` event.

So you don't need to remove handler. Simply handle `TextChanged` event and update the other control.

In the below example, I have 2 `TextBox` control which you can type in both and the reverse string will be shown on the other:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox2.Text = new string(this.textBox1.Text.Reverse().ToArray());
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = new string(this.textBox2.Text.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Using above pattern you can simply use your `MakeBinary` and `MakeAscci` methods. You should only have reversible methods.

Answer (score 1):

You sholud use `TextChanged` event. When user types in one textbox you handle it in `TextChanged` handler.

to avoid infinite loop you can unsubscribe from `TextChange` event at the beginning and subscribe again at the end of handler:

```
private void TextChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textbox1.TextChanged -= TextChangedHandler;
     textbox2.TextChanged -= TextChangedHandler;

     // set textbox values

     textbox1.TextChanged += TextChangedHandler;
     textbox2.TextChanged += TextChangedHandler;

}
```

Comment: textchanged in both text box will creates an infinite loop: am not the down voter

Comment: @Roma There is no infinite loop when you use `TextChanged` event of two `TextBox` controls to sync text of them. The `Text` property checks and if the new value is the same as previous value, then it will not raise the `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

use `TextChanged Event` check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for detail

code

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// update your target text bx over here
}
```

> Create `TextChanged Event` only for one box for both box it will
>   create infinite loop

Comment: There is no infinite loop when you use `TextChanged` event of two `TextBox` controls to sync text of them. The `Text` property checks and if the new value is the same as previous value, then it will not raise the `TextChanged` event.